# Setting a timezone in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web app and want to set the timezone to EST.  Is there a simple way to do this? Maybe in the web.config?

I believe I also have to change the database timezone too?

Comment: **I believe I also have to change the database timezone too?** If so, you can make Date and time changes in your server and it will automatically reflect in your server database.

Comment: yeah thanks, i'll have to do that too. Do you know if I can change the app in web.config to handle date functions in EST?

Comment: For that you can first validate the date in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**I believe I also have to change the database timezone too?** If so, you can make Date and time changes in your server and it will automatically reflect in your server database.

You can use below function to validate the date first.

```
DateTime dt; 
string Temp1 = "Your Date"; 
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt)) 
{ 
     // If it is a valid date 
     string date = dt.ToShortDateString(); 
     string time = dt.ToShortTimeString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use the (relatively) new [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) class to do this.

I'm a bit into the Unix world philosophy of storing UTC and then displaying in local time, so I have to code the other way, as Windows has the hardware clock set to local time.